# How to reduce execution time in algorithm by replacing for loop in python

Tags: python, algorithm, execution-time

I'm trying to solve an algorithm problem,consider the following list:

```
l =  [100, 20, 50, 70, 45]
```

in this problem I have to find the average of the elements up to index i:

```
i = 0
100
i = 1
(100 + 20) //2 = 60
i = 2
(100+20+50) // 3 = 56
...
```

the final result should be stored in a list:

```
[100, 60, 56, 60, 57]
```

this is my code so far:

```
from functools import reduce
def meanScores(l):
      def av(x):
            return reduce(lambda a, b: a+b,x)//len(x)

      return [av(l[:i]) for i in range(1,len(l)+1)]
```

It works fine the problem is that when I submitted it, I faced a time limit execution.I think the problem is the for loop since it takes a lot of time when `len(l)` is more than ten-thousand. Previously I used `sum()` to do the averaging but that took a lot of time too, when I turned that `sum()` to `reduce(lambda a, b: a+b,x)//len(x)` the algorithm got faster(It solved more test cases).I think that if instead of an for loop I use another function(like lambda) then the problem is solved.So do you think there is a way? thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you calling meanScores repeatedly? or is it a single use each time?

Comment: This code might be more suitable on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @OrDinari it is single use

Comment: @Torxed thanks for mentioning that,I am new to this sites.

Comment: Has your teacher mentioned avg() and array slicing?

Comment: what does the `,x` in the `lambda` do?

Comment: Replacing the efficient builtin `sum` with a home-made, complicated `reduce` makes no sense. Timing it, I find that using `reduce` the way you did is consistently 15 times slower than `sum`. You probably changed something else at the same time if you found that you improved your running time.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner that `x` is for the reduce which is passed to the lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [`numpy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and get the average dividing by the index+1 of the cumsum list.

```
import numpy as np

l =  [100, 20, 50, 70, 45]

l_cumsum = np.cumsum(l)
l_indices = np.arange(1,len(l)+1,1)
l_average = np.divide(l_cumsum, l_indices).tolist()

print(l_average) # Outputs [100.0, 60.0, 56.666666666666664, 60.0, 57.0]
```

It should be pretty fast, O(n), since `numpy.cumsum` is very optimized already. If you still want it faster you could multithread it.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you sum the whole array each time so the cost is quadratic, but can be linear if you reuse the previous result each time. Think about it.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, can I implement this idea in my own code( I mean using reduce and lambda) or I have to change the whole algorithm(like in the solutions that are suggested for this question)?

Comment: I can't see how reduce() could fit into the solution since it reduces an array to a single value, that already takes linear time and we got only a single value and we need a whole array of the same size. Taking reduce() out of the possible solution you don't have much of your original code. So yeah, better if you start from zero.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is iterate only once on the list:

```
i = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]


def meanScores(l):
    if len(l) == 0: #Check is its an empty list
        return []
    res = [l[0]] #the first item is the first item in both lists(l)):
        res.append(float((res[i-1]*i + l[i])) / (i+1)) #Use the previous result to calculate the new result
    return [int(x) for x in res]
```

For using the previous results i take the previous sum (which is the prev avg * i), add the new number, and divide it by i+1.

Comment: I think it should had been up to him to find out the solution.

Comment: @Or Dinari tnx for the solution but there is a problem with it: for `100, 20, 50, 70, 45]` the answer should be `[100, 60, 56, 60, 57]` but your algorithm gives :`[100, 60, 56, 59, 56]`. Also the final answers should be rounded the smallest integer so  if possible, please change `/` to `//` in you post.

Comment: Your correct did not take into account floating point, should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

1. Each time you run the `av` function, it reduces the *whole* list. Since calling `av` in your list comprehension, you're calling `av` more times than you need. You should be calculating your list of sums (using `av`) only once, and deriving your sums as you iterate through `l`.
2. Since you are only summing up to `i`, you shouldn't be reducing the *whole* list. You should be slicing the first list `l[:i]`, then running your `reduce()` against the shortened list.

Answer (score 1):

As complete solutions have already spoiled the game, here is a working one in O(n).

Note that you can very often avoid manipulating indices yourself in Python. Here, we can use `enumerate` with a start value of 1 to keep track of the number of values we summed.

```
def means(lst):
    sum = 0
    out = []
    for n, new_val in enumerate(lst, 1): # we enumerate starting with n=1
        sum += new_val
        out.append(sum/n)
    return out
```

Some tests:

```
lst =  [100, 20, 50, 70, 45]
print(means(lst))
# [100.0, 60.0, 56.666666666666664, 60.0, 57.0]

print(means([]))
# []
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented with linear time complexity i.e O(n). A sample can be as follows just to give you an idea, how can you do it.

```
l =  [100, 20, 50, 70, 45]

a = [0] * len(l)

a[0] = l[0]

temp = a[0]

for i in range(1, len(l)):
    a[i] = (temp + l[i]) / (i + 1)
    temp = temp + l[i]

print(a)
```

```
Output
[100, 60.0, 56.666666666666664, 60.0, 57.0]
```